# How to know which View object in GridView was selected to open Context Menu

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm learning to build an android application for educational purposes, but I've hit a problem, and was wondering if anyone could advise?

I've created a grid. Each square in the grid contains placeholder images when initialised for the first time. When you 'long press' a grid square, a Context Menu appears. A user should then be able to opt to upload an image from their image gallery, which is resized and replaces the placeholder image, or they can input text into a grid square creating a TextView object to replace the placeholder image.

I can't figure out how to determine which View item in the grid the context menu was opened from. I've given them all a tag, but don't know how to access it, because the View object isn't passed in to the onContextItemSelected method.

Appropriate code from my GridAdapter is here:

```
 private Integer[] ids = {
        android.R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable.image};


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, parent, false);

        holder = new Holder();

        holder.mView = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid);

        holder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mImageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return convertView;
}


public static class Holder {
    View mView;

    ImageView mImageView;
}
```

}

Appropriate code from my Grid class:

```
   Gridview gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

  registerForContextMenu(gridview);

 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.uploadmenu, menu);
    }


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.group_item1:
         //store image in grid square
```

I've got this method to modify the image in my GridAdapter class, but I don't know how to retrieve the position and resourceId of the grid item that was clicked in order to open the Context Menu.

```
  public void updateImage(int position, int resourceId)
  {
    mThumbIds[position] = resourceId;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Please do not re-ask the same questions again. Edit the original to improve or clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `onCreateContextMenu` use this piece of code,

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
position = (int) info.id;
```

This will give you the position. Save it as a class attribute and use it inside on `onContextItemSelected`.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is really helpful. When I tried that it currently returns position 0 for all of them. Do you know how I would set the position?